# Need help Making the UIAlert View have a action

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

This is the part of the .m I am trying to configure: 
This is my UIAlertView:

```
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score %d", _score];
UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Game Over"
                                                     message:message
                                                    delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Play Again"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
[av show];
```

I am trying to make the above  UIAlertView so when I click on Play Again, it does this:

```
[self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction repeatAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction runBlock:^{

        }], [SKAction waitForDuration:0.05],  [SKAction waitForDuration:0.05]]] count:4], [SKAction runBlock:^{
            _canRestart = YES;
        }]]]];
```

this is my .h:

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface MyScene : SKScene

@end
```

---

I have added what vborra has said, and i am still getting the  Use of undeclared Identifier 'alertView' message.  is declared in the .h, and this is the code i have in the .m that i am trying to configure

- (void)alertView:UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
          [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction repeatAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction runBlock:^{

  ```
      }], [SKAction waitForDuration:0.05],  [SKAction waitForDuration:0.05]]] count:4], [SKAction runBlock:^{
          _canRestart = YES;
      }]]]];
  ```

Comment: Why does your alert only have one choice? Why can't the alert be cancelled without playing again?

Comment: Please read the docs for `UIAlertView`. It tells you all about the delegate and the methods you should implement.

Comment: because i want it to restart my game

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `UIAlertViewDelegate`, it gets called whenever an alert gets pressed: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html

```
UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Game Over" message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Play Again" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Then in your delegate method(`- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`):

```
[self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction repeatAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction runBlock:^{

    }], [SKAction waitForDuration:0.05],  [SKAction waitForDuration:0.05]]] count:4], [SKAction runBlock:^{
        _canRestart = YES;
    }]]]];
```

Then the game will restart when the 'OK' button was pressed.

Comment: i used vborra's code, but it says "use of undeclared identifier 'alertView' " what should I do?

Comment: did you set your delegate i the .h file?

Comment: Change the current line to @interface MyScene : SKScene <UIAlertViewDelegate>

Comment: I had that already, and I am still getting the use of undeclared identifier 'alertView'message